# What am I missing in my approach to add new records to my database in VB.NET Applicaton?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2010

I have a data table (Named "Effects") from Access in my VB.Net Userform.

[image: The Form with Details from Database]

I have two buttons (AddEffect.Click and SaveEffect.Click) that use **ADD NEW**,  **END EDIT** and **UPDATEALL**. This works whilst the app is open.

A new record appears in the **GRIDVIEW** with the Data I inputed into the various textboxes.

[image: GRIDVIEW OF EFFECTS TABLE]

```
    Private Sub AddEffect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles AddEffect.Click
               
            Me.EffectsBindingSource.AddNew()

           End Sub

 Private Sub SaveEffect_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SaveEffect.Click
            
            Me.EffectsBindingSource.EndEdit()
            Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DatabaseDataSet)
    
                End Sub
```

However, **there are two issues**.

1. The ID Number of the New Record generated is always a -ve integer.
2. When I click the SAVE ENTRY button and restart the application, the changes have not been saved.

Other examples I look at online do not resemble my issue.

EDIT:

[image: The Tables I am Using...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The ID Number of the New Record generated is always a -ve integer.

That's exactly as it should be. The value generated by your application is only temporary. The final ID is generated by the database when you save. The temp value is negative to ensure that it doesn't clash with anything that's already in the database.

> When I click the SAVE ENTRY button and restart the application, the changes have not been saved.

You are almost certainly over-writing your database. The way file-based databases should work is that you add a source file to your project and that gets copied to the output folder along with your EXE. It's that copy that your app connects to while you're debugging. If you create a new copy the next time you build, which is the default, you lose any changes you made to the old copy.

To avoid that, select your data file in the Solution Explorer, open the Properties window and set *Copy to output directory* to *Copy if newer*. That way, a new copy will only be created if you explicitly delete the old copy or make a change to the source file.

The reason for the dual-file approach is that you're supposed to keep your source file clean and free of test data so that the copy created when you build a Release version of your app will be ready to deploy with a fresh app.

Comment: Hi jmc, thankyou for the quick and considered response. I have followed your instructions; however I do not think they solved the issue. As well as the 'Effects' table, I have another that I am able to edit and watch update in Access in real time. The difference with that table ('Locations') is that the rows already exist and I am merely editing and updating them. Are you saying that there is no issue with my code above?

Comment: I think the ability to watch the Locations table update in realtime is because it is enabled in the TableAdapterManager; I do not believe that I can have multiple of these or have one work on multiple tables from the same data source...

Comment: If you have done things correctly then there is no issue with your code. The `UpdateAll` method should call `Update` on every relevant table adapter associated with your `DataSet`, so it should matter what changes you make to what table. If I'm not mistaken, that `UpdateAll` method should return an `Integer` that indicates the number of records affected by the operation. One the rare and distant occasions I used a typed `DataSet`, I called individual `Update` methods and I believe that `UpdateAll` sums them all. What is that number in your case?

Comment: As for the ID values, if you want the temporary negative values replaced in the app by the final values generated by the database, you need to actually get those values. See [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?659052) for how to do that.

Comment: I am unsure how to see that number. I have been using this method fine for the Locations table. Now that I am using and wishing to update in-app multiple tables I am running into issue. Each table has a Primary Key column with Unique values in it. I am now getting an error on the UPDATE ALL method as it says "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." This has had me following a lot of google searchs this afternoon.

Comment: That error message means that your table adapter has no SQL UPDATE command associated with it, which almost certainly means that your database table doesn't have a primary key. The SQL statements for table adapters are generated automatically but UPDATE and DELETE statements cannot be generated if there's no PK to identify the record to be updated or deleted.

Comment: *"I am unsure how to see that number"*. It's the return value of a function. How do you usually see the value returned by a function?

Comment: Jmcilhinney, as I said before all three of my Database tables have Primary Keys with Unique Numbers; they have the little key icon next to them. I will add screenshot above.

Comment: So, if not the lack of PK; what other reason could be generating this error? Testing it, the Locations Table is still updating fine, but the other two are causing crashes and the error: "Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows." with the UPDATE ALL command.