# 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection with modified rows.'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

In my application I have three tables all from the same Access database. I have used the Wizard in Visual Studio Express 2019. This is an extension of [my unresolved question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64334393/what-am-i-missing-in-my-approach-to-add-new-records-to-my-database-in-vb-net-app)

```
Database.TwixBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.NPCsBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.EffectsBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Database.DatabaseDataSet)
```

I have these three tables ("Twix","NPCs",and "Effects"). The above code automatically runs every 15 seconds, like an autosave feature. My issue is when I try to edit "NPCs" or "Effects" I recieve the following error:

> 'Update requires a valid UpdateCommand when passed DataRow collection
> with modified rows.'

[image]

Most of the online answers in regard to this error are solved by ensuring each table has a Primary Key column that is recognised by Visual Studio in order to automatically generate the necessary commands to edit, updte, delete etc.

However, I am stumped because I have PKs on each table.

The only thing I can think is that it has something to do with the 'TableAdapterManager,'

[image]

[image]

ALthough I have no clue at this point.

EDIT: I have replaced the UPDATE ALL with individual UPDATES, but the same problem persists...
[image]

```
Database.TwixBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.TwixTableAdapter.Update(Database.DatabaseDataSet)
Database.NPCsBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.NPCsTableAdapter.Update(Database.DatabaseDataSet)
Database.EffectsBindingSource.EndEdit()
Database.EffectsTableAdapter.Update(Database.DatabaseDataSet)
```

Comment: Personally, I don't use the table adapter manager. There's not much point unless you're saving data to multiple tables. I always just create the appropriate table adapter. That said, it looks like you need to set those `EffectsTableAdapter` and `NPCsTableAdapter` properties. I'm not sure why they're not already set but you should be able to set them manually. If you created the typed `DataSet` before adding those tables to the database, that might be the reason.

Comment: I have tried individually calling them, as per the EDIT in my question above. But still the same outcome; Twix is fine and the others cause the same crash. (Sorry Twix is what I call the Locations Table for some reason...)

Comment: I'd be inclined to trash the DataSet and recreate it. I've not experienced an issue like this so I'm not exactly sure what to recommend looking at.

Comment: Jmc, I would not know what to do differently so I do not see much to gain by swapping out the dataset for another one. There is clearly some difference between Twix and the other two tables.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, I just wanted to thank you for your help today! thanks to you I worked through my problem and I learned a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Right click on your tableadapter (on the header, not the Fill command), and choose *Configure*

[image]

- Click *Advanced Options* and verify that "Generate I/U/D" is ticked

[image]

When this isn't ticked, the resulting TA doesn't have any DML statements built:

[image]

If your SELECT statement doesn't select the column that is set as the primary key in the database, then this *Generate IUD* tickbox may be greyed out, or it will be ticked but the DML statements won't generate. Pay attention to the final page of the wizard. Here is what happened when I made a table "Other" that had no primary key:

[image]

INSERT generates, because it's easy to generate an insert on a keyless table, but update and delete cannot be generated

If you don't select the PK column you get a warning:

[image]

---

It's important that your DB tables have a PK; it's not the same thing to declare some datacolumns of a datatable in a dataset to be a primary key. A Dataset is not a database; it may have more or fewer tables/columns and the presentation and datatypes of row data do not have to match the DB. I can see that your dataset screenshot shows some tables have PKs declared in the DataSet side, but this is not a statement that they are definitely PKs on the DB side

Feel free to delete the DataTable; it will delete the TableAdapter too. You can then recreate that one TA by right click, new, tableadapter.. SELECT * FROM table

If you hadn't already realized, remember that you can (and should) declare more queries per tableadapter than just keeping with the basic Fill, which appears to be a `SELECT * FROM` without a WHERE clause in your case. Personally I always make my first query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = @id` because it's really rare that you want to download a whole table.. You can leave the default as a WHEREless query, but consider adding others, such as `SELECT * FROM Twix WHERE Location = @location` and naming the query `FillByLocation`. In code you can then fill just the locations you want, rather than downloading 10000 Twixes into the app just to show some of them (with a rowfilter, i guess)

Answer (score -1):

This question and answers helped me figure out my problem.

**NOTE** that if your problem is your table (for example you forgot to set a primary key and you go back and fix it in SSMS while debugging) you will need to find the menus in Caius answer, ensure boxes are ticked, **and hit Finish if nothing else.**

This will refresh something about the statements(unclear what), and allow this to work. Otherwise you will continue to receive these errors as if you'd fixed nothing, and probably continue to search to no avail.